# Not a valid ERC-20 token

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, myetherwallet

I've created a contract.

When I try and add it in to MKEF to MyEtherWallet it says it is not a valid ERC-20 Token?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x84f7f794867642a47ce577fe0d9745da6ac37c44#code

Here is the contact address.

I am very new to this as you can probably tell.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question more of a suggestion but try the Parity Wallet which has built-in token creation. I will take a closer look at your code and see why in the mean time

[Parity Wallet Github](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases)

Answer (score 0):

Your contract doesn't follow the [EIP-20 standard specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md).

It is missing several methods like `balanceOf`, `approve`, `transferFrom`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For it to be a valid token/compliant you must implement the erc-20 Standard. You can either implement the missing functionality directly in your contract or inherit from an abstract contract. Redeploy with the changes and it should be ok!